# extract RGB values from different raster-files with different shapefiles

Tags: r, loops, rgb

I have a dataset with 50 different rasterfiles and 50 different shapfiles. The rasterfiles are orthophotos from a forest and each orthophoto has a belonging shapefile where the tree crwons are marked with points.
I now want to extract the RGB values of the crowns with a for loop.
Until now I wrote a normal for-loop but here is the problem that I just have one iterator but actually I need two (one for the list of shapefiles and one for the list of orthophotos). I also tried a nested for loop but then it is the problem that one shapefile is analysed with all orthophotos and so the previous data always gets overwritten.

So this is my code for the nested loop:

```
    library(rgdal)
    library(rgeos)
    library(exactextractr)
    library(sp)
    library(sf)
    library(raster)


    #gets list of shapefiles
    sites <- list.files("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/Praktikum Mitacs/Data Files/ManualTreetops_2019_RGB/ManualTreetops_Finished",pattern = "*.shp")

    #removes ".shp" file extension
    sites <- sub(".shp","",sites)

    orths <-  list.files("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/2019_ortho",pattern="*.tif", full.names = TRUE)

    output <- list()

    #loops through list of files
    for (i.site in sites) {


    #each time through i.site represents a different site
    tt <- st_read("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/Praktikum Mitacs/Data Files/ManualTreetops_2019_RGB/ManualTreetops_Finished", i.site)

    #create 1 m radius circles around each treetop
    crowns <- st_buffer(tt, 1)


    for(i.orth in orths) {

        setwd("C:/Users/Kai/OneDrive - UT Cloud/Documents/2019_ortho")

        oo <-  brick(i.orth)

        #extracts the mean band values for each crown
        #much faster than extract in raster package
        crown.rgb <- exact_extract(oo,crowns,"mean")


       }

      output[[i.site]] <- crown.rgb
      #add results to list of output from for loop

    } #end of for loop
```

Does anyone has an advise how I can compare a shapefile just with one orthophoto, but doing it automaticaly in a loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can specify the `for`-loop to iterate over the numbers 1 to 50, then subset `sites` and `orths` from there: `for (i in seq_along(sites)) { i.site <- sites[i] ; i.orth <- orths[i] }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R loop over two or more vectors simultaneously - paralell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46909024/r-loop-over-two-or-more-vectors-simultaneously-paralell)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you explain a liittle bit more in detail what you mean by that, please? I don't really get it in which way I should subset `sites` and `orths` and why I should iterate over 1 to 50. Sorry, I am a beginner in R...

Comment: Ok sorry for the inconvenience, I think this is the answer for my question! Thank you very much, I should be able to implement it.

Comment: No worries, you did a good try! Basically, a `for`-loop iterates over some vector and applies the "body" (the code in the `for`-loop) to each element of that vector. What you were doing, is iterating over `sites` directly. However, you wanted to iterate over `sites` and `orths` simultaneously, grabbing the same element from both. Essentially, you want `sites[1]` and `orths[1]`, then `sites[2]` and `orths[2]`, etc... So, instead, we just write the `for`-loop for 1 to 50 (the full length of `sites` and `orths`), and write `sites[i]` and `orths[i]` in the body. I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Yes, this was the exact problem!  Sites and orths should iterate simultaneously. I implemented it like you said and it works perfectly now.  Thank you for your help and the detailed answer.